# C++ Object to java, attributes are not correct after passing the object to java (int, double)

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I want to export a C++ classobject of an DLL to java. The problem is, that after I export the object to java, all the property values like int and double are not correct in java - Why is that so? How can I prevent this in order to get this to work? Here are some screenshots of what I mean.

The first paragraph of the following logs are printed from my C++ DLL. The second paragraph is printed from my java program.

**First execution of my program**
[image: First execution of my program]

**Second execution of my program** 
[image]

As you can see, all the values are different of my human object in C++ and java. The value of the age property changes everytime after execution of my java class, but the attributes  SalaryInt and SalaryDouble in java change consistently upon execution. While debugging, I can look at my object for approximately a second. While this second, the object looks like this:

[image]

After the "second", it looks like the following image:

[image]

Here you can see my code.

**HumanBean.java**

```
package at.xxxx.xxxxx;

public class HumanBean {

    String name;
    int alter;
    int gehalt;
    double gehaltDouble;

    public HumanBean(String name, int alter, int gehalt, double gehaltDouble) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.alter = alter;
        this.gehalt = gehalt;
        this.gehaltDouble = gehaltDouble;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAlter() {
        return alter;
    }
    public void setAlter(int alter) {
        this.alter = alter;
    }
    public int getGehalt() {
        return gehalt;
    }
    public void setGehalt(int gehalt) {
        this.gehalt = gehalt;
    }
    public double getGehaltDouble() {
        return gehaltDouble;
    }
    public void setGehaltDouble(double gehaltDouble) {
        this.gehaltDouble = gehaltDouble;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HumanBean [name=" + name + ", alter=" + alter + ", gehalt=" + gehalt + ", gehaltDouble=" + gehaltDouble
                + "]";
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**
(For now I wont post the native method declarations, the only method I am calling is erstelleHuman)

```
import at.xxxx.xxxx.HumanBean;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("library: "
                + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

        HumanController humanController = new HumanController();

        HumanBean tati = HumanController.erstelleHuman();
        System.out.println("----------------------  erstelleHuman -----------------------");
        System.out.println("Tati Age = " + tati.getAlter());
        System.out.println("Tati SalaryInt = " + tati.getGehalt());
        System.out.println("Tati SalaryDouble = " + tati.getGehaltDouble());

    }

}
```

**My Wrapper .cpp-File**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Human.lib")
#include "HumanHeader.h"
#include "HumanController.h"
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Class:     HumanController
 * Method:    erstelleHuman
 * Signature: ()Lat/xxxx/calculatorhuman/HumanBean;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_HumanController_erstelleHuman(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj) {
    Human exportierterHuman = Human::erstelleHumanExport(45, "Dragan Stankovic", 1769.34, 987563);

    jclass cls = (*env).FindClass("at/xxxxx/calculatorhuman/HumanBean");
    //jclass cls = (*env).FindClass(env, "at/xxxxx/calculatorhuman/HumanBean");

    jmethodID cid = (*env).GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;IID)V");
    std::cout << "------------------------Java_HumanController_erstelleHuman ----------------" << endl;
    std::cout << "exportierterHuman Objekt c++ Name " << exportierterHuman.name << endl;
    std::cout << "exportierterHuman Objekt c++ Alter " << exportierterHuman.alter << endl;
    std::cout << "exportierterHuman Objekt c++ GehaltInt " << exportierterHuman.gehaltInt << endl;
    std::cout << "exportierterHuman Objekt c++ GehaltDouble " << exportierterHuman.gehaltsDouble << endl;
    return (*env).NewObject(cls, cid, exportierterHuman.name, exportierterHuman.alter, exportierterHuman.gehaltInt, exportierterHuman.gehaltsDouble);

}
```

**.cpp-File, which is being wrapped by me**

```
#include "HumanHeader.h"
#include <iostream>

Human::Human(int x, string y, double z, int g) {
    alter = x;
    name = y;
    gehaltsDouble = z;
    gehaltInt = g;
}

 Human Human::erstelleHumanExport(int alter, string name, double gehaltDouble, int gehaltInt) {
     return Human(alter, name, gehaltDouble, gehaltInt);
 }
```

**Header of the .cpp-file being wrapped**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    class Human
    {
    public:

        int alter;
        string name;
        bool volljaehrig;
        double gehaltsDouble;
        int gehaltInt;

        Human(int x, string y, double z, int g);


        // funktion mit dllExport
        static __declspec(dllexport) void triggerGeburtstagExport(Human human);
        static __declspec(dllexport) bool isVolljaehrigExport(Human human);
        static __declspec(dllexport) void gebeGehaltAusExport(Human human);
        static __declspec(dllexport) Human erstelleHumanExport(int alter, string name, double gehaltsDouble, int gehaltInt);


    };
```

Comment: If `exportierterHuman.name` is of type `std::string`, then you should convert it to java String (using `NewStringUTF `). Now you are passing it directly to NewObject: `NewObject(cls, cid, exportierterHuman.name,`

Comment: @marcinj thanks, that was the solution! Would you mind to explain, why the string corrupted all the other values?

Comment: Passing a `std::string` by value entails copying it to the stack. But a `std::string` will take up multiple word-sized slots, so your real values are after the `std::string`, never seen or used by `NewObject`. Your compiler should have emitted a warning that passing a `std::string` to a variadic function is a [bad idea](https://godbolt.org/z/40sW8I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @macinj, I got it working. I simply changed

```
return (*env).NewObject(cls, cid, exportierterHuman.name, exportierterHuman.alter, exportierterHuman.gehaltInt, exportierterHuman.gehaltsDouble);
```

to the following code snippet ->

```
jstring name = (*env).NewStringUTF(exportierterHuman.name.c_str());
return (*env).NewObject(cls, cid, name, exportierterHuman.alter, exportierterHuman.gehaltInt, exportierterHuman.gehaltsDouble);
```